# при наведении выполнить CSS внутри этого блока

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

При наведении на красную обсласть, объект внитри должен подчеркиваться, но у меня получается, что подчеркивание происходит только при наведении непосредственно на буквы. Где я не прав в написании кода?

```css
.parent {
    display: block;
    padding: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: red;
    
 }

.parent > span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 2px; }
  .parent > span::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    transition: width .3s; }
  .parent > span:hover::after {
    width: 100%; }
```

```html
<a href="" class="parent"><span>Жми сюда!</span></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вам нужно чтобы было подчеркивание при наведении на весь блок, то состояние :hover необходимо задать блоку, на который и должно срабатывать наведение. У Вас же указано что при наведении на span

**Ответ на вопрос:**

```
.parent:hover > span::after {
    width: 100%; 
}
```

[**Пример на codepen**](https://codepen.io/ZloyDed/pen/mzWELz)

Comment: Блин! Спасибо! Упустил этот момент